# Python - Read random lines from a very big file and append to another file

Tags: python

we are trying to get random lines of about 1M from a very big file which may have around 3M records in it. The selected random lines needs to be written into a third file.
Do you have any suggesstions for us?

Comment: Do you want to choose a line without a bias? Because if not, you could easily seek to a random location and then find a `\n`.

Comment: Your first sentence is poorly written and I don't understand it. What's the relationship between "lines" and "records"? How many lines/records are in the source file? How many do you want in the output file? How large are the lines/records?

Comment: @FranciscoCouzo that's an interesting idea but also risks outputing the same line multiple times unless you track which `\n` 's you've already found and skip them. I think that adds its own bias (disard if random numbers happen to be close to each other) but its been too long since I've studied stats!

Answer (score 8):

For future reference, since the other answers already gave a solution that work for workloads that fit in memory:

```
import random

def reservoir_sampling(l, k):
    it = iter(l)
    try:
        result = [next(it) for _ in range(k)]
    except StopIteration:
        raise ValueError("Sample larger than population")

    for i, item in enumerate(it, start=k):
        s = random.randint(0, i)
        if s < k:
            result[s] = item

    random.shuffle(result)
    return result

with open('input.txt') as infile, open('output.txt', 'a') as outfile:
    for line in reservoir_sampling(infile, 1000000):
        outfile.write(line)
```

The algorithm is called reservoir sampling, and needs `O(n)` time and `O(k)` memory, depending on your needs you might or might not need the `random.shuffle` call.

Comment: It looks sophisticated and interesting, but eventually you're just reading first _k_ lines of file (one-letter identifiers?!) and shuffle them. Not what the OP intended.

Comment: @volcano How did you miss the entire middle part of the algorithm?

Comment: @StefanPochmann, how did you miss that _next_ on file iterator will read a line from the file? I was sure that it will, but still I tested it. Voila - suspicion confirmed.

There's no magic - line *result = [next(it) for _ in xrange(k)]* will read first _k_ lines into a list - so that 0k promise is wrong too.

Comment: @volcano Are you being dense on purpose? Yes, the reservoir starts with the first k lines of the file, but then the next block of code **updates the reservoir** using the remaining lines. The function is textbook [Algorithm R](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservoir_sampling#Algorithm_R) (plus shuffling).

Comment: @volcano I **have** tried it. File with ten lines, asking for five lines, got lines 3, 4, 9, 10 and 5. Explain.

Comment: I was wrong. Apologies. I am trying to remove the downvote - but I cant't unless the answer is edited :(

Comment: @volcano I expanded a little bit the explanation, you should be able to remove the downvote now.

Comment: @FranciscoCouzo, thanks, I actually upvoted - the most interesting answer provided, when you get to the gist. I apologize for shooting from the hip :(

Comment: @FranciscoCouzo, just one thing - this is the real issue, not detracting from the beauty of the solution. If your file contains than _k_ line, the building of the preliminary result will fail...

Comment: @volcano Do you mean if `len(l) < k`? There's not much to do in that case, notice `random.sample` will raise a `ValueError` exception in that case.

Comment: @FranciscoCouzo, actually, this is the case where regular cycle will be better that list comprehension

Comment: @volcano Your edit broke the invariant that `len(reservoir_sampling(l, k)) == k`, which I think is pretty important, if you'd like you should add a comment on what to do if that's not desirable.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126179/discussion-between-volcano-and-francisco-couzo).

Comment: What does the 1000000 do?

Answer (score 4):

3 Million records of, say, 100 character lines isn't huge - it all depends on what hardware you are using. You could just do:

```
import random

with open('input.txt') as infile, open('output.txt', 'a') as outfile:
    outfile.writelines(random.sample(infile.readlines(), 1000000))
```

This is one of the faster ways to do it and its simple. So, then its a question of seeing if it works for you.

Comment: What does the 1000000 do?

Comment: @Superdooperhero - That's the number of values selected from the original sample. The question was about getting 1 million samples from a 3 million item file. `readlines` would read 3,000,000 lines and `sample` would emit 1,000,000 lines.

Answer (score 2):

You can just use readlines() and dump the file into a list. Then you can simply generate 1 million random numbers. Of course they have to be within the range of the size of the list/ number of lines in the file and each time a random number is generated access the line at that location in the list and write it to the file you want to move it in.

Comment: OP said the file is very big, which would rule out `readlines` since it reads the whole file into memory.

Comment: @FranciscoCouzo Unless they're the typical noob who thinks a few megabytes is very big. Seen that many times.

Comment: Hey, I thought you deleted yours so i wrote mine! Anyway, I agree. +1 and etc... I gave an example so  I think I'll keep mine up too.